# An or operator in a return?

Tags: c, recursion, return

I just saw something like:

```
return (m(s1 + 1, s2) || m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));
```

What does the `||` mean in a `return` statement?
Here, `m` is a function; `s1` and `s2` are strings.

Comment: It means the same thing there that it means anywhere else.  It is the logical or operator.

Comment: It is not so much "in a return", as much as you evaluate that expression and then return the result of it.

Comment: It means the return statement returns either `0` or `1`.  If the left-hand call to `m` returns `1` (or any other non-zero value), the right-hand call won't be made (and the result will be `1`); if the left-hand call returns `0`, the right-hand call will be made, and the return value will be `0` if the RH call returns `0` and `1` otherwise.  This is the normal short-circuiting behaviour of the `||` operator.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can't count on a 1, it could be some other non-zero value.

Comment: @nicomp: what can't be counted on to be a 1?  The question is tagged 'recursion' and '`m`' is specified as the function, so it is probable that `m` is a recursive function and this `return` statement is in `m`.  There could be other `return` statements in the function; it cannot be guaranteed that those return `0` or `1` because we've not been shown them.  However, this `return` statement is only going to return `0` or `1` because the `||` operator only evaluates to `0` or `1`.

Comment: @nicomp the result of a boolean expression is `0` or `1`. There are other situations where you might expect that, but is as you say, such as the library function `isupper()` and more, which return **non-0** result.

Comment: The standard disagrees with you, @nicomp: "The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0."  ([C2011 6.5.14/3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14p3)).  All values other than 0 are interpreted as true in boolean context, but relational operations always evaluate to either 1 or 0.

Comment: Crazy how many languages can't do `||` and `&&`right. `5 || 0`  and `2 && 4` should evaluate to `5` and `4` and not `1` and `1`.. It's sad.

Comment: @Sylwester: it's crazy that there are any languages where `||` or `&&` do not evaluate to a boolean value.  They're logical operators, not numeric operators. … — … Or, more validly, there are different languages with different designs, and the design of C is as described (where the logical operators return `0` or `1`) and other languages can do anything they choose because they aren't C.

Comment: @Sylwester I am sorry that so many crazy/sad languages can't get it right. The question is about the logical `||` not the bitwise `|`. In your first example the result of `5 | 0` is indeed `5`, but in your second example `2 & 4` evaluates to `0`, not `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `return (m(s1 + 1, s2) || m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));` can be rewritten in this form:

```
if ( m(s1 + 1, s2) )
{ 
    /* if left part not null, return 1, without 
       evaluationg the right part */
    return 1;
}
else if ( m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1) )
{  
    /* if left was 0, test right part */
    return 1;
}
else
{ 
    /* if both are null, return 0*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing special about using the `||` operator in a `return` statement. A statement like:

```
return <expression>;
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = <expression>;
return temp;
```

(where `temp` has the same type as the function's return type).

So your statement is equivalent to:

```
int temp = (m(s1 + 1, s2) || m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));
return temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

`||` is a short circuiting or, meaning that the expression will stop executing at the first true value as the result.
It has the same effect as this code but is a lot shorter and easier to read if you know what `||` means:

```
if (m(s1 + 1, s2)) {
  return 1;
}
if(m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1)) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

If `m` printed something to screen it would only print once if the first call returned a true value. You also have `&&` which does something similar but stops at the first false value. `return (m(s1 + 1, s2) && m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1));`  is the same as:

```
if (!m(s1 + 1, s2)) {
  return 0;
}
if (!m(s1 + 1, s2 + 1)) {
  return 0;
}
return 1;
```

The obvious reason to use the operators is that you need less boilerplate.

Comment: In C, "implicit `int`" as shown in `auto value = m(s1 + 1, s2);` went the way of the dodo in C99 (though there are certainly C compilers that would still accept it).  In C, you don't use `auto` — there is no reason to do so and writing `auto` would be effectively wrong (very non-idiomatic).  In C++, the rules are dramatically different — but C++ is a very different language from C.

Comment: The code in this answer is not equivalent to the original, as the original necessarily returns 0 or 1, while this code returns a value returned by `m`, which may differ.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It was wishful thinking. Of course C would implement `||` and `&&` wrong :-(. Anyway fixed the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my edit didn't need bindings anymore, but thanks for the comment. My C experience predates C99 so I might be a little rusty :-p